# Delete all data from model if user do not have data in another model

Tags: django

If user has data in the `Data` model and `Bank` model everything is ok but if user do not have data in `Bank` model and only in `Data` model - all data from `Data` model must be removed.

How to do?

```
class Data(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    something = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Bank(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    number = models.IntegerField()

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty straightforward in querying both models, and if no values deleting the data from `Data`.

Answer (score 0):

in one of your views function (or in a cron job... your question is vague actually):

```
bank = Bank.objects.get(user=user)
if not bank:
    data = Data.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
```

warnings:

- `user` must have a valid value (ie: must be defined)
- this code doesn't check for anything, it just performs what you asked

adding a `foreign_key` from `Bank` to `Data` (or viceversa, it depends on the strength of the relation) could be a valid change to your classes. Like this we don't know how `Data` and `Bank` are related to each other

Comment: Data and Bank are not related. The user that has the data in the model `Data` must also be data in `Bank` model. If there is no data in Bank model -> all the data from the model `Data` must be removed. That is all.

Comment: and if I add a relations between Data and Bank? For example. ForeginKey(Bank) in my Data model?

Comment: If you delete a Bank, the default behaviour is to delete all the foreign keys too. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete